# chartkick why is x-axis a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I've created a custom hash but the x-axis is showing up as a date. I want it to just show the value in the hash (1,2,3 etc...). This is my first time using chartkick so I'm lost as to why this is happening.

What's being displayed is January 1, 2000 with the value of 504, February 1, 2000 with value of 499, March 1 etc....

When I set @chart_hash as an array, instead of a hash (which is what is shown below), I get times in the x-axis instead of dates.

application.html.erb

```
<head>
<title>SampleApp</title>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

_chart.html.erb

```
<%= line_chart @chart_hash %>
```

@chart_hash

```
{0=>504, 1=>499, 2=>499, 3=>504, 4=>509, 5=>514, 6=>514, 7=>521.5, 8=>516, 9=>511, 10=>511, 11=>511, 12=>506, 13=>501, 14=>501, 15=>506, 16=>511, 17=>516, 18=>511, 19=>518.5, 20=>522.5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  In the past chartkick could only use date objects, but now if you pass the discrete option it will use regular numbers.

_chart.html.erb

```
 <%= line_chart @chart_hash, discrete: true %>
```